# Error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'groupindicator' in package 'android'

Tags: android, layout, expandablelistview

I am following the tutorial located [here](http://android-adda.blogspot.com/2011/06/custom-expandable-listview.html).  But I keep on getting an error with my XML code relating to the android:groupindicator.

Here is the relevant xml.

```
           <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingTop="70dp" >

                <expandablelistview
                    android:id="@+id/android:list"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:groupindicator="@drawable/group_indicator" >

                    <textview
                        android:id="@+id/android:empty"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:text="@string/main_no_items" >
                    </textview>
                </expandablelistview>
            </LinearLayout>
```

The exact error is as follows.

```
[2012-03-21 21:51:44 - FoodSubs] C:\.......res\layout\food_display.xml:55: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'groupindicator' in package 'android'
```

I have checked everything over several times but I am just not having any luck.  I am sure it is going to be something obvious but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: could be the SDK problem? What is the minSDK you have defined?

Comment: <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" /> - 2.1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

change `android:groupindicator` to `android:groupIndicator`

Comment: Ok, that did solve that problem. Weird that it was being so picky about that.  Thank you.